# GraphQLError type incorrect

Tags: angular, graphql

I have a Apollo resolver that throws a new GraphQLError:

```js
throw new GraphQLError(
  'Username already taken', {
  extensions: {
    code: 1004,
  },
});
```

In my Angular component I want to get the code in the extensions:

```js
public createUserName(userName: FormControl): void {
  this.apollo.mutate<User>({
    mutation: userOperations.CREATE_USER,
    variables: {
      name: userName.value,
      sessionId: this.session.id,
    }
  })
  .subscribe({
    next: (user) => console.log(user),
    error: (e: GraphQLError) => {
      console.log(e)
      console.log('=========================================')
      const error = {...e}
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
}
```

For some reason, `e` is a string build from the `name` + `message` on the error:

[image]

The problem here is that the returned object is not of type `GraphQLError` but I cannot figure out what type it should be in the Angular component.